# changing Home Screen Quick Actions icon position

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, homescreen, 3dtouch

Q: how to position icon to the left side of the text in UIApplicationShortcutItems ?

Observation: i was adding Home Screen Quick Action to my app and my custom icon is on the right side of the Text.
I looked into multiple big apps like facebook, snapchat etc and observe systematically left side icon.
Apple documentation and Official App always have right aligned icons.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think you can choose the position of the icon:

Here's the answer from an Apple Staff member:

```
The icon position is not configurable, and iOS will swap sides of the 
icon depending on where the app icon is placed.  For example, if the 
app icon on the left side of the screen the icon in the shortcut menu 
will appear on the left, but if the app is on the right side of the 
screen then the shortcut menu items will be on the right.  In general, 
the shortcut menu icons will be positioned so that they are directly 
above or below the app's icon.
```

From: https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/20568